# Material3 action bar doesn't allow to set background color programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

Trying to set a custom color for an certain Activity programmatically, but action bar doesn't react even when set `setBackgroundDrawable(null)`. Any thoughts? Thanks

Style:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ToolbarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.Material3.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/material3_primary</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/ic_nav_back_dark_theme</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ToolbarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    title = "Temp"
    supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"))) //it doesn't work
}
```